# Precautions and Customs to observe when traveling in Morocco

Tags: morocco, cultural-awareness

What precautions should my husband and I take and/or customs should we follow while traveling in Morocco. We are not Muslim and are unsure of this country's level of tolerance for Americans and Christians.

Comment: My sister almost got thrown off a train for kissing in public. I had already been to Morocco before her and had been warned of that so I was surprised she didn't hear the same warnings.

Comment: Advice you get here and on web is probably good enough. ie behave sensibly in areas flagged as possibly sensitive. But, my daughter (30's) has just been in Morocco for just under a week. She loved it (few comments - many fantastic photos of her and friend doing all sorts of fun things). If you wanted to email me I could pass your query on to her for comment. I doubt this is needed but may end up being of interest in other ways as well. [email address on my profile page  - click my name at end of this comment to see profile].

Answer (score 6):

As with any foreign country with a very different culture from your own:

- Wear modest clothing (eg. no bare shoulders for women)
- Don't wear obvious national or religious symbols (eg. a big American flag patch on the back of a jacket would not be a good idea)
- Avoid alcohol if possible, or consume it in moderation in private (eg. in your own hotel room)
- Avoid obvious display of jewelry or other symbols of wealth
- Sign up with the [Smart Traveler Enrollment Program](https://step.state.gov/step/) for US citizens